# ¿Cómo se puede hacer para iniciar una variable sólo una vez?

Tags: java

Hola el problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo un programa de bingo con java y estoy intentado hacer que cante linea cuando los números estén alineados

Para ello he hecho un contador que va incrementando y cuando en una linea llega a 5 canta linea, pero el problema es que solo puede hacerlo una vez y me lo hace tres veces una por cada fila al estar el contador reseteandose cada vez que hay 5 en una fila.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería, pondré un ejemplo del problema que me da aquí abajo:

Y una salida de este programa es:

```
  @  X  @  X  X  @  X  @  6
  @  X  X  @ 13  X  @  9  @
  X  @  X  @  @  X  @  X  1
Seguent numero (s/n)?: s
Nou Numero: 6 
 Aquest Numero el tens, t'ho marco amb una 'X' 
  @  X  @  X  X  @  X  @  X
  @  X  X  @ 13  X  @  9  @
  X  @  X  @  @  X  @  X  1
Has dado con la linea
Seguent numero (s/n)?: s
Nou Numero: 13 
 Aquest Numero el tens, t'ho marco amb una 'X' 
  @  X  @  X  X  @  X  @  X
  @  X  X  @  X  X  @  9  @
  X  @  X  @  @  X  @  X  1
Has dado con la linea
Seguent numero (s/n)?: s
Nou Numero: 9 
 Aquest Numero el tens, t'ho marco amb una 'X' 
  @  X  @  X  X  @  X  @  X
  @  X  X  @  X  X  @  X  @
  X  @  X  @  @  X  @  X  1
Has dado con la linea
Has dado con la linea
Seguent numero (s/n)?: s
Nou Numero: 1 
 Aquest Numero el tens, t'ho marco amb una 'X' 
  @  X  @  X  X  @  X  @  X
  @  X  X  @  X  X  @  X  @
  X  @  X  @  @  X  @  X  X
¡¡BINGO!!!
Has dado con la linea
Has dado con la linea
Has dado con la linea el código aquí
```

Comment: hola! te faltó mostrarnos tu programa

Comment: @Alfabravo ya he puesto la parte de código que hice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo único que necesitas es hacer un `break` después de mostrar el mensaje:

```
if (contador == 5) {
    encontrado = true;
    System.out.println("LINEA!!");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ok. muchas gracias

Comment: pero sigue habiendo otro problema porque he puesto un mensaje con printf de "se ha echo Linea en la fila %d",i+1; y cuando me hace linea en otra fila me canvia el numero de fila del mensaje